# not styling late loading div

Tags: javascript, css, select, html, drop-down-menu

i have two select boxes

one of them is dynmaic one of them static

the dynamic one is loading with javascript (get and fill facebook friends) like below

```
function (response) {

                      //console.log(response); 
                      var xxx = '<select id="friend" class="msdropdown" name="friend">';
                      for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                          xxx = xxx + '<option value"' + response[i]['uid'] + '">' + response    [i]  ['name'] + '</option>';
                       }
                      xxx = xxx + '</select>';
                      friendslist.innerHTML = xxx;
                  });
```

i give class to both of the select boxes but the dynamic one is not working i think because of lateness

how could i solve this problem?

Comment: And what are the styles ? It does not matter with CSS that you add your elements dynamically or not, they will get styled if the rules match.

Comment: the style has javascript files it reproduce some divs and some tags which options of select box

Comment: first the page loading and at that moment the static select box got the style correctly after 1-2 seconds my dynamic select box comes to the screen but no style

Comment: I understand what dynamically means ;-) When you check the CSS in the console, do you see the rules overriden by some others for the dynamically created select ?

Comment: i look in firebug and i see no divs and other tags are become like the static select box is. what should i see in the console for css

Answer (score 0):

In your case the css file is loaded since the static select is being styled so I don't think it's a timing issue. If you inspect the dynamic select box in firebug does it have the same class / styles applied to it?

Comment: it has same class name off course but not same class/style applied to the dynamic select box